# How to expand Jpanels into GridBagLayout

Tags: java, jpanel, size, gridbaglayout

My Question is how to expand my 3 JPanels into my GrigBadLayout.
I added 2 photo, the first sample and displays the result and the second as I would like it to be.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class ListMembersView extends JPanel{
    JPanel headerPanel;
    JPanel containerPanel;
    JPanel footerPanel;

    public ListMembersView(){

        initComponents();
        initLayout();
    }

private void initComponents(){

    this.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255),5));

    headerPanel = new JPanel();
    headerPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    containerPanel = new JPanel();
    containerPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    footerPanel = new JPanel();
    footerPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
}    

private void initLayout(){    
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    /*Not expand JPanel?*/
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    c.gridx=0; c.gridy=0; 
    this.add(headerPanel,c);

    c.gridx=0; c.gridy=1; 
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    this.add(containerPanel,c);

    c.gridx=0; c.gridy=2; 
    this.add(footerPanel,c);

}
}
```

My result is:

[image]

I would like be that way:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `columnWeights = {1}` and `rowWeights = {1, 1,1}` and `fill` to BOTH like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class ListMembersView extends JPanel{
    JPanel headerPanel;
    JPanel containerPanel;
    JPanel footerPanel;

    public ListMembersView(){

        initComponents();
        initLayout();
    }

private void initComponents(){

    this.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255),5));

    headerPanel = new JPanel();
    headerPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    containerPanel = new JPanel();
    containerPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    footerPanel = new JPanel();
    footerPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
}    

private void initLayout(){    
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    this.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] {1};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] {1, 1, 1};
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    /*Not expand JPanel?*/
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    c.gridx=0; c.gridy=0; 
    this.add(headerPanel,c);

    c.gridx=0; c.gridy=1; 
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    this.add(containerPanel,c);

    c.gridx=0; c.gridy=2; 
    this.add(footerPanel,c);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(new ListMembersView());
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The `fill=BOTH` teels, that panels should be extended in both directions.

the `weights` tells how to divide the space beetwen the rows or columns proportionally to the overall sum of their weights.

Comment: Thanks you very much!! The solution is valid,

Comment: I now want to give a percentage to the panels, the center panel has more height, if I find the solution I share it.

Comment: just change the line:  'gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] {1, 1, 1};' to  'gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] {1, 2, 1};' or something else